# How do I import the exported nodes?

Tags: importing-exporting

I have exported the nodes from Drupal 7 using the node_export module, and I want to import those nodes in my new Drupal 8 site.

Is there any way to achieve this?

The exported nodes look like the following.

```
array(
  (object) array(
      'vid' => '311713',
      'uid' => '84015',
      'title' => 'How to Create Pro-Level Videos on iPhone Featuring the Storyographist',
      'log' => 'Edited by Donna Cleveland.',
      'status' => '1',
      'comment' => '0',
      'promote' => '1',
      'sticky' => '0',
      'vuuid' => '40b3f8ec-95ba-4699-8192-8dcc731039b4',
      'ds_switch' => '',
      'nid' => '272977',
      'type' => 'article',
      'language' => 'und',
      'created' => '1501684200',
      'changed' => '1516617288',
      'tnid' => '0',
      'translate' => '0',
      'uuid' => 'f85d16e8-484a-4e03-8e7b-c1576f857ffc',
      'revision_timestamp' => '1516617288',
      'revision_uid' => '1',
      'body' => array(
        'und' => array(
          array(
            'value' =>
```